# Cannot Access DropdownList in EditItemTemplate inside Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, itemtemplate, edititemtemplate

My TT.aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal ID="lit1" Text='<%#Eval("E_Name")%>' runat="server">

            </asp:Literal>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Eq" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name">

            </asp:DropDownList>

        </EditItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [E_Name], [Problem], [Solution] FROM [Equipment] WHERE ([O_ID] = @O_ID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="O_ID" QueryStringField="TT" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Parts]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My TT.aspx.cs

```
        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        Literal xx = (Literal)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lit1");
        String x =  xx.Text;
        DropDownList x1 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("Eq");
        x1.SelectedValue = x;
    }
```

I'm a newbie to asp.net and I'm only testing with this code. The problem I have is that the 2nd `FindControl("Eq")` always returns `null` while the first one (for the Literal) returns the correct value. I tried setting the edit index of the gridview to e.NewEditIndex but doesn't seem to work.

Basically what I want to happen is if the user clicks on Edit on a row, the original databound value, which is in the label, is selected in the dropdownlist.

Can anybody guide me through this, please?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247279/binding-dropdownlist-inside-gridview-edititemtemplate

Comment: I have already checked it out before asking, but I don't see how it relates. I say this because he is implementing the code in the `RowDataBound` method while I'm implementing it in the `RowEditing` method. Also I already tried `GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;` but it didn't work. Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Answer (score 0):

The `RowEditing` event just gives the row index being edited. You need to set the edit row index to the grid and rebind it. And if you need to set a value or need to bind a control inside `EditItemTemplate` you have to do it in `RowDateBound` event, as you will be re-binding grid in `RowEditing` event so the `RowDataBound` event will also give you the `EditItemTemplate`'s controls.

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247279/binding-dropdownlist-inside-gridview-edititemtemplate)

```
protected void gv_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  // grid view's edit index has been changed so rebind it
  gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
}

protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
          ddList.SelectedValue = "set your value here";
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 but you only need to set the EditIndex if you are manually binding the GridView using the DataSource property and DataBind method. This answer would work without the RowEditing event re-binding the GridView.

Comment: I'll try it now but quick question; will clicking the edit button invoke the `RowDataBound` method? If not, then how can I invoke it programatically from the `RowEditing` method?

Comment: Pressing edit button will invoke `RowEditing` event and in row editing event upon rebinding of grid the `RowDateBound` event will fire, as @Sean pointed out you are using `DataSource` property so you will not need to rebind the grid just set `EditIndex` the `RowDataBound` will be fired automatically.

Comment: Now `Literal xx = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("lit1");` is returning null. Is this the right way to reference "lit1" from the `RowDataBound` method?

Comment: I managed a workaround solution, a bit messy but does the job. I'm saving the text inside the label in a global variable, once I read it in the `RowEditing` method, and then read it in the `RowDataBound` method