# RowState is not changing to edit mode (infact "editable" row just doens't get caught by RowDataBound)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowstate

For the past 2 weeks I have been experience the *most unbelievably excellent* scenarios with GridView and its related controls...properties. I praise to anyone who had encountered these issues earlier.

The latest issue is with `RowState` check at `RowDataBound`.

When I click on the Edit linkbutton in GridView, by right the RowState must be `edit`. However, RowState remains `normal` in following code, thus not allowing me to do anything that should be done for row editing mode.

Why is this happening? I have tried out every possible `bit-wise` combination to capture the `edit` for RowState. Still no luck...

```
protected void GridView3_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
```

Here's what I have discovered on debug mode...
When edit button is clicked for Row 3 (edit index is 2) for an example, the RowDataBound is fired.
The event is going through each Row from index 0 to 1 but it doesn't come to index 2. Therefore the row which is in edit mode NEVER seem to go through RowDataBound event. All the other related issues that I am having with TemplateFields of edit mode are inter-connected to this issue.

Comment: Why don't you hookup [RowEditing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @rene Oh I tried doing RowEditing... then I read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247279/binding-dropdownlist-inside-gridview-edititemtemplate)

Comment: @rene [you were absolutely right about others stuff being screwed up...specially on aspx side where exceptions just *slide away* or *pass on to someone else in cs*...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24777781/1389394)